# Trouble filtering through rows in a Material UI Table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui, textfield

When I perform a search in my TextField, the rows show up correctly in the console.  However, this is not true for the actual table (which does not change at all).  I've tried setting the result of my search to a new array, but that makes my TextField read-only.  Any further help troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

Here is where state is set and the function I'm using to fetch data:

```
    const [rows, setRows]: any = useState([]);
    const [checked, setChecked]: any = useState(false); 
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<readonly string[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!checked) {
            setChecked(true);
            fetchData();
        }
    }, [checked]);

    const fetchData: any = async () => {
        const response: any = await axios.get(`/api/layer_data`);
        setChecked(true);
        let dataRows: any[] = response.data;
        dataRows.map((dataRow: any) => (dataRow.isSelected = false));
        console.log('response: ', response.data);
        setRows(dataRows);
    };
```

This is my handleSearch function for filtering through my data:

```
    const handleSearch = (e: any) => {
        const inputSearch = e.target.value;
        rows.filter((row: any) => {
            if (inputSearch == '') {
                return rows;
            } else if (row.product_id == inputSearch) {
                console.log(row);
                return row;
            } else if (row.sku_id == inputSearch) {
                console.log(row);
                return row;
            } else if (row.description == inputSearch) {
                console.log(row);
                return row;
            } else if (row.units_per_layer == inputSearch) {
                console.log(row);
                return row;
            } else if (row.in_stock == inputSearch) {
                console.log(row);
                return row;
            } else if (row.bin == inputSearch) {
                console.log(row);
                return row;
            }
        });
    };
```

Here is how I've defined my TextField:

```
<TextField
                        onChange={(e) => handleSearch(e)}
                        label="Search..."
                        fullWidth
                        variant="outlined"
                        className={style.padding_right}
                    />
```

Here is the mapping function I'm using to create my table:

```
{rows.sort(getComparator(order, orderBy)).map((row: any, index: any) => {
                                            const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.product_id);
                                            const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                                            return (
                                                <StyledTableRow
                                                    hover
                                                    onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.product_id)}
                                                    role="checkbox"
                                                    aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                                                    tabIndex={-1}
                                                    key={row.product_id}
                                                    selected={isItemSelected}
                                                >
                                                    <StyledTableCell padding="checkbox">
                                                        <Checkbox
                                                            color="primary"
                                                            checked={row.isSelected}
                                                            inputProps={{
                                                                'aria-labelledby': labelId
                                                            }}
                                                            onChange={handleCheckbox}
                                                            value={index}
                                                        />
                                                    </StyledTableCell>
                                                    <StyledTableCell align="right">
                                                        <input
                                                            type="number"
                                                            min="0"
                                                            required
                                                            defaultValue="0"
                                                            onChange={(e) => handleInput(e, index)}
                                                        />
                                                    </StyledTableCell>
                                                    <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.sku_id}</StyledTableCell>

                                                    <StyledTableCell component="th" id={labelId} scope="row" padding="none" align="right">
                                                        {row.product_id}
                                                    </StyledTableCell>
                                                    <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.in_stock}</StyledTableCell>
                                                    <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.bin}</StyledTableCell>
                                                    <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.units_per_layer}</StyledTableCell>
                                                    <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.description}</StyledTableCell>
                                                </StyledTableRow>
                                            );
                                        })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your handleSearch function does not actually update the state `rows`, also you shouldn't mutate the original set of rows, I recommend the following:

1 - Create two states for your rows, 1 to hold the original set of rows, and another for the filtered rows

```
const [rows, setRows]: any = useState([]);
const [filtered_rows, setFilteredRows]: any = useState([]);
```

2 - Set both `rows` and `filtered_rows` at the end of your `fetchData` function

```
const fetchData: any = async () => {
    ...
    setRows(dataRows);
    setFilteredRows(dataRows);
};
```

3 - In your `handleSearch` function, create some variable `updated_filtered_rows` to capture the result of your filter, and update update `filtered_rows`

```
const handleSearch = (e: any) => {
    const inputSearch = e.target.value;
    const updated_filtered_rows = rows.filter((row: any) => {
        ...
    });
    setFilteredRows(updated_filtered_rows);
};
```

4 - use the state `filtered_rows` to create your table

```
{filtered_rows.sort(getComparator(order, orderBy)).map((row: any, index: any) => {
    ...
})}
```

Comment: In step 3, is `updateFilteredRows(updated_filtered_rows);` supposed to be `setFilteredRows(updated_filtered_rows);`?

Comment: oops yeah, let me edit, I use update as my verb, thanks !

Comment: I found that when I made these changes, my TextField became read-only.

Comment: these changes have no effect on your TextField, check for anything else you've done...